# Can't boot to my usb to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

Recently I deleted Ubuntu gnome desktop from my new laptop dual booting with windows 8 and also repaired the start up so that it would go to windows automatically. However now I want to install Ubuntu Mate 15.10 with my usb, I burned its iso file to my usb using Unetbootin and it works fine on my other laptop and it boots ok from usb, but it won't boot using my new laptop. Also to mention that when I went to delete Ubuntu partitions from Disk Management I saw 2 drives (Recovery Partition and EFI system Partition) which can't be deleted. ( I think they are created during Grub reparation when I couldn't boot to Ubuntu and it used to go straight to Windows 8. I used ubuntu's boot repair tool )
I just want to install Ubuntu again on my laptop but I can't even boot from my usb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: the efi and recovery partitions were created by Windows.
They are needed for booting systems and recovering Windows.

Second: Unetbootin and other 3rd party tools don't work well.
The USB drive was not configured properly to boot in efi mode.

Use the built-in **diskpart** tool from within Windows OS.
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.

When booting from the USB drive select the entry with UEFI.

If you still have access to an **Ubuntu system** you can use the **disks tool**.
Open it and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and start restoring.

Comment: Hi again I did as you said and copied the content to USB drive. However it didn't boot again.. on other laptop it says "an operating system wasn't found. try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system". is it because of iso file or something else? Btw, ty so much for your time. @A.B.

Comment: @Aratoud : Disable hibernation and fast boot in Windows and shutdown the PC (do NOT reboot) - if possible disable intel rapid start in BIOS as well. :) ... by the way ... I am cl-netbox ... =)

Comment: @Aratoud not my answer ;)